# Gravity Forms Stripe subscription only accepting integers

Tags: regex, stripe-payments, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm using Gravity Forms with the Stripe add on.

The customer can pick to pay the total in full or over 3 months. When paying over 3 months, the form uses a subscription feed which is then automatically cancelled after 3 payments.

When paying the full amount, Stripe processes the payment perfectly. When selecting to pay over 3 months, it only works when the total amount is an integer e.g. £136. If the total amount is something like: £136.67, it fails and I get the following validation error:

***This value must match the regex pattern. (/\A[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\z/ does not match for the value payover3months_3_1month_136.67).***

Can Stripe not process subscriptions unless it's a whole number?

It's also worth noting that I'm using the [Ecommerce Gravity Wiz Perk](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-ecommerce-fields/).

The following fields are in use when paying over 3 months:

- Subtotal
- Tax (3%)
- Discount (66.66%)
- Total

The form will be working out: Subtotal + 3% Tax - 66.66% Discount = Total. The Discount is in place to divide the subtotal by 3.

Comment: Your character class is missing a `.` to match a float value.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I was running an older version of the Gravity Forms Stripe Add On (2.5). Updating to 2.5.4 addressed the issue.

Gravity Forms support informed me that minor updates are not available for automatics updates via WP Admin. This means you'll need to follow these steps to update:

1. Select the "Deactivate" option for the plugin you're trying to
   update
2. Select the "Delete" option for the plugin you're trying to update
3. Answer yes when prompted to delete the files. This step deletes the
   plugin's folder and the files inside.
4. Select the option to "Add New" plugin
5. Select "Upload"
6. Browse to the location where you saved the newly downloaded zip file
   and select it
7. Click "Install Now". You should see the message "Plugin installed
   successfully." This step recreates the plugin's folder and the files
   inside.
8. Click "Activate Plugin"

It's important that you DO NOT use the Uninstall [plugin] button in the Forms > Settings area - this will remove your data.

Comment: We also had this issue and upgrading does solve the problem. What was odd for us is that Gravity Forms wasn't prompting us to upgrade this add-on, but did for the others. We were still using Gravity Forms Stripe Add-On v2.5 and the newest version is 2.7.1. If you're seeing this issue you may still have to manually upgrade using the steps outlined here, even though you should be able to do it through the WordPress admin.